# What can I use to automatically send sms texts before calendar events?

Tags: automation, calendar, sms

After Google calendar dropped support for SMS event reminders (June 27, 2015), is there any other solution to receive sms notifications 15 minutes before calendar events?

Comment: send SMS event reminders to only you or all participants?

Comment: At least to me. Sending to all participants is a nice-to-have

Answer (score 2):

This is an overkill, but..... the open source CRM  CiviCRM has that capability.  You can schedule event reminders and send an SMS and/or email to all attendees.

See: [CiviCRM | SMS Text Messaging - What is SMS](http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/sms-text-messaging/what-is-sms/)

And make sure you checkout the [Demo Here](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/)